# can I ingest apache tomcat ser logs using apache2 module in filebeat

Tags: java, elasticsearch, kibana, filebeat, apache-modules

I would  like  to ingest the access logs  of  my sever using  apache2 module , but  i'm wondeing  if it's  supported  by it or  not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Apache2 module of filebeat **"parses access and error logs created by the Apache HTTP server."** so yes you can.

Comment: Thanks a lot for  your response,  I've already resolved this  problem as  you mentioned